# How do I solve this problem in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, forms

```
$("#id_address_input").bind("blur",function(e){
    //do a lot of stuff, set variables.
});
```

So, I have a text box that when the user gets off of it...this thing gets fired and processes.

Ok, the problem is this:

When the user clicks the form Submit button, this blur thing gets fired.  And in the middle of processing, the form submits.  This messes everything up.

How do I fix this?
I thought about adding a delay on form.submit, so that it'll finish processing. But, that's a bad idea because I haven idea how fast the user's browser and/or Google Maps is.

Comment: *"And in the middle of processing, the form submits."* Really? Are you doing something that yields? (`setTimeout`, ajax...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `blur` handler, you must be doing something that "yields" to the browser (a `setTimeout`, an asynchronous ajax call, etc.), because otherwise, the browser will not interrupt your JavaScript code to submit the form. See below for an example proving it.

If you *are* doing something that yields to the browser from within the `blur` handler, you'll have to prevent the form submission with a `submit` handler and then have it get submitted when everything (including the various actions in the `blur` handler) is ready. This may be a bit complicated.

The best answer is to remove whatever it is in the `blur` handler that's yielding to the browser. If you can't do that, you're probably looking at a locking counter on the form and having the submission handler check that locking counter:

```
// Somewhere, ensure the form has a lock count of zero
$('#theForm').data('submitlock', 0);

// Your blur handler increments the lock
// In the blur handler:
$('#theForm').data('submitlock', $('#theForm').data('submitlock') + 1);
// ...and when done
$('#theForm').data('submitlock', $('#theForm').data('submitlock') - 1);

// The submit handler might look something like this:
$('#theForm').submit(function() {

    // Get a jQuery wrapper for the form
    var $this = $(this);

    // Locked?
    if ($this.data('submitlock') > 0) {
        // Yes, set up the recheck and prevent form submission
        setTimeout(recheck, 10);
        return false;
    }

    // Function to periodically retry submission
    function recheck() {
        // Still locked?
        if ($this.data('submitlock') > 0) {
            // Keep waiting
            setTimeout(recheck, 10);
        }
        else {
            // Nope, submit the form using the underlying DOM object's submit function
            $this[0].submit();
        }
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ecuye3/2) (a version of our blocking example below, but updated to yield to the browser)

Beware that if your form is being submitted to a new window, you may run afoul of pop-up blockers (since the new window isn't in *direct* response to a user click). But if you're not doing something like that, you're in good shape with the above.

---

Here's an example of a `blur` handler causing a substantial delay (four seconds) before the form is submitted ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ecuye3)):

HTML:

```
<form action='http://www.google.com/search' target='_new'>
  <label>Search for:
    <input type='text' name='q' value='foo'></label>
  <br><input type='submit' value='Search'>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[name=q]').blur(function() {

  var end, counter;

  display("Start blurring");
  counter = 0;
  end = new Date().getTime() + 4000;
  while (new Date().getTime() < end) {
    ++counter;
    if (counter % 100000 == 0) {
      display("Still blurring");
    }
  }
  display("Done blurring");

});
```

Put your cursor in the text box, and then click Search. You'll see a four-second delay, and then the search will open in a new window. I've tested this on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera (on Linux), IE6 on Windows 2000, and IE7 on Windows XP. All behaved the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Do your form submit using javascript. Write a function which calls on onsubmit and check to see if the things that were supposed to happen on blur event have finished. Then only submit your form

Answer (score 1):

Try a flag?

```
var doSubmit = true;

$("#id_address_input").bind("blur",function(e){
    doSubmit = false;
    //do a lot of stuff, set variables.
    doSubmit = true;
});

$("#form").submit(function(){
    if(doSubmit){
        return true;
    }else{
        // keep checking until doSubmit is true
        window.setInterval(function(){if(doSubmit){$("#form").submit();}},1000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use the `"submit"` event? And in that case, you wouldn't want to return `true`...

Comment: needs to return true instead of submit() at the end.